# Which is the book in the Protestant Bible containing most quotes of verses from other Bible books?

Tags: biblical-basis, bible, protestant-bible

It'd be just interesting to know this as a fact. Also, to have an objective criteria, what will be the answer if we consider the percentage of verses in the corresponding book that are quotes(instead of the number). The later will allow to compare short and long books in this regard.

Comment: I think it would be either one of the books of the law, Psalms, or Isaiah.

Comment: Do you mean to include repetition, paraphrase, and re-narration, or just direct quotation?

Answer (score 2):

The closest answer that I could find regarding **quotes** is from research using a [compilation](http://www.kalvesmaki.com/LXX/NTChart.htm) of Old Testament quotes in the New Testament (in English). This shows Romans (at 48), followed by Hebrews (at 41), and then Matthew at 35.

To state it as percentages, Hebrews would have the highest percentage, as it has only 303 verses. It's at 14%, followed by Romans at 11%, then by Matthew at 3%.

However, there are places where the Old Testament books quote other Old Testament books, and similarly where the New Testament quotes New Testament books.

The New Testament quotes within itself only a couple of times, according to this [research by Don Stewart](https://www.blueletterbible.org/faq/don_stewart/don_stewart_1210.cfm). Peter quotes Paul, and Paul quotes Luke, but these two do not change the rankings of most quotes within a book as provided by the first resource mentioned. Similarly, there are few places where the Old Testament quotes itself, such as Isaiah quoting Deuteronomy, but these smaller numbers are not enough to overcome the higher counts of New Testament books quoting Old Testament books.

Besides these online resources, also check out The Ultimate Cross-Reference Treasury, Prepared by Jerome H. Smith (Copyright © 2016 by Jerome H. Smith)

Answer (score 0):

Evidently the New Testament book Revelation has the most Old Testament quotations at 249 followed by Matthew at 96.

https://www.blueletterbible.org/study/pnt/pnt08.cfm

Jesus Christ quotes Deuteronomy the most.

https://bible.org/seriespage/introduction-deuteronomy

Comment: The Revelation figure doesn't really stack up - referencing themes, or utilizing similar terminology and imagery are not the same as quoting.

Comment: The link specifically says they are quotations.   "Quotations from the Old Testament in the New Testament"    So, unless we redefine what "quotations" means, I guess we have the answer.

Comment: Sources can be unreliable. [Here is another one](http://catholic-resources.org/Bible/Quotations-NT-OT.htm) that counts 0 actual quotes in Revelation. Based on my own knowledge of the Bible and what constitutes a quote, this source is a little more accurate. Prove it wrong if you like, by finding a significant number (more than five say) of actual quotes in Revelation - should be pretty easy if there are over 200 right?

Comment: Your source looks more unfinished than accurate, stopping at 2 Peter and missing 1,2,3 John, Jude, and Revelation.

Comment: ... *if* they actually have **quotes** - don't just go by looks, go by what *is*.  Where are the quotes that you are implying are in those books?

Comment: Here's your source "Many of the references in the following table are direct quotations; others are paraphrases or close allusions to older scriptural texts."  Surely, had he finished his work to Revelation, he would have found "close allusions".  So, until you can discredit BlueLetterBible.org, we'll go with that.

Comment: Revelation only has 404 verses. It's hard to believe it could have 249 quotes in 404 verses and yet still have its own narrative.

Comment: Quotes may be a verse or two words.  In any event, go with Matthew.